# Create lagged columns using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Background:**
Lets say I have this code

```
library(data.table)

#reproducibility
set.seed(45L)

#make table
dt <- data.table(V1=c(1L,2L),
                 V2=LETTERS[1:3],
                 V3=round(rnorm(4),4),
                 V4 = 1:12)
dt
```

for which I get

```
> dt
    V1 V2      V3 V4
 1:  1  A  0.3408  1
 2:  2  B -0.7033  2
 3:  1  C -0.3795  3
 4:  2  A -0.7460  4
 5:  1  B  0.3408  5
 6:  2  C -0.7033  6
 7:  1  A -0.3795  7
 8:  2  B -0.7460  8
 9:  1  C  0.3408  9
10:  2  A -0.7033 10
11:  1  B -0.3795 11
12:  2  C -0.7460 12
```

and I want to append create 10 columns of the lags of V3.

**Question:**
Is there a way to do it within the "data-table" paradigm.

**More details:**
If it were a data.frame then I could do a loop.

```
dt <- as.data.frame(dt)


for(i in 1:10){
     dt <- cbind(dt, shift(x = dt[, 3], 
                           n = i, 
                           fill = NA, 
                           type = "lag"))
     names(dt)[ncol(dt)] <- sprintf("lag_%06d",i)
}

dt
```

for which I get:

```
> dt
   V1 V2      V3 V4 lag_000001 lag_000002 lag_000003 lag_000004 lag_000005 lag_000006 lag_000007 lag_000008 lag_000009 lag_000010
1   1  A  0.3408  1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
2   2  B -0.7033  2     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
3   1  C -0.3795  3    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
4   2  A -0.7460  4    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
5   1  B  0.3408  5    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
6   2  C -0.7033  6     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
7   1  A -0.3795  7    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA         NA
8   2  B -0.7460  8    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA         NA
9   1  C  0.3408  9    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA         NA
10  2  A -0.7033 10     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408         NA
11  1  B -0.3795 11    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408
12  2  C -0.7460 12    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033     0.3408    -0.7460    -0.3795    -0.7033
```

There has to be a more elegant way.  Something that can handle much larger data much more quickly and efficiently.

Now what if I wanted to first do this, to make 10 lags, on column V3, then on V4, without presupposing their names.  I could simply make nested for loops, but again I suspect that data.table has something good (great?) to offer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also possible to do it all in 1 `data.table` call. This could be particularly useful if you need to a lot of columns:

```
cols <- c("V3","V4")
dt[, (paste0("lag_",rep(cols, each = 10), "_", rep(1:10, times = length(cols)))) := 
            unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, 1:10, type = "lag")), recursive = F), .SDcols = cols]
```

The `paste0(...)` code sets up the column names the way we want and then the `unlist(lapply(...))` code gets the lags for each column in the order we want. To see how each works you can run them individually (if running the `unlist(lapply(...))` you'll have to substitute in `dt[,c("V3","V4")]` for `.SD`.

```
dt[,1:9]
#    V1 V2      V3 V4 lag_V3_1 lag_V4_1 lag_V3_2 lag_V4_2 lag_V3_3
# 1:  1  A  0.3408  1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2:  2  B -0.7033  2   0.3408        1       NA       NA       NA
# 3:  1  C -0.3795  3  -0.7033        2   0.3408        1       NA
# 4:  2  A -0.7460  4  -0.3795        3  -0.7033        2   0.3408
# 5:  1  B  0.3408  5  -0.7460        4  -0.3795        3  -0.7033
# 6:  2  C -0.7033  6   0.3408        5  -0.7460        4  -0.3795
# 7:  1  A -0.3795  7  -0.7033        6   0.3408        5  -0.7460
# 8:  2  B -0.7460  8  -0.3795        7  -0.7033        6   0.3408
# 9:  1  C  0.3408  9  -0.7460        8  -0.3795        7  -0.7033
#10:  2  A -0.7033 10   0.3408        9  -0.7460        8  -0.3795
#11:  1  B -0.3795 11  -0.7033       10   0.3408        9  -0.7460
#12:  2  C -0.7460 12  -0.3795       11  -0.7033       10   0.3408
```

Comment: Wrapping in one call is less readable but slightly faster than my answer according to my benchmark. +1

Comment: Certainly less readable, I just thought it might be helpful if he had to lag a lot of different columns (that way not a lot of typing is needed). However, for only a few columns, I'd definitely opt for your solution

Comment: I wrapped it in a loop.  I did have a lot of columns, but wow.  I think data.table might be my new best friend... numerically speaking.

Comment: This almost worked for me, maybe some data.table updates have changed things. Posted modified version below.

Comment: I think data.table borked it because it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `shift` considers this type of user-demand. When parameter `n` for `shift` is a vector, `shift` will return a list for each shift in `n`:

```
dt[, sprintf("V3_lag_%06d", 1:10) := shift(V3, 1:10, type = 'lag')]
dt[, sprintf("V4_lag_%06d", 1:10) := shift(V4, 1:10, type = 'lag')]

#     V1 V2      V3 V4 V3_lag_000001 V3_lag_000002 V3_lag_000003 V3_lag_000004 V3_lag_000005
#  1:  1  A  1.2322  1            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 2:  2  B  1.6094  2        1.2322            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 3:  1  C  0.4016  3        1.6094        1.2322            NA            NA            NA
# 4:  2  A -0.2730  4        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322            NA            NA
# 5:  1  B  1.2322  5       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322            NA
# 6:  2  C  1.6094  6        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322
# 7:  1  A  0.4016  7        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094
# 8:  2  B -0.2730  8        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016
# 9:  1  C  1.2322  9       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730
# 10:  2  A  1.6094 10        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322
# 11:  1  B  0.4016 11        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094
# 12:  2  C -0.2730 12        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016
# V3_lag_000006 V3_lag_000007 V3_lag_000008 V3_lag_000009 V3_lag_000010 V4_lag_000001
# 1:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 2:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA             1
# 3:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA             2
# 4:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA             3
# 5:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA             4
# 6:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA             5
# 7:        1.2322            NA            NA            NA            NA             6
# 8:        1.6094        1.2322            NA            NA            NA             7
# 9:        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322            NA            NA             8
# 10:       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322            NA             9
# 11:        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094        1.2322            10
# 12:        1.6094        1.2322       -0.2730        0.4016        1.6094            11
# V4_lag_000002 V4_lag_000003 V4_lag_000004 V4_lag_000005 V4_lag_000006 V4_lag_000007
# 1:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 2:            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 3:             1            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 4:             2             1            NA            NA            NA            NA
# 5:             3             2             1            NA            NA            NA
# 6:             4             3             2             1            NA            NA
# 7:             5             4             3             2             1            NA
# 8:             6             5             4             3             2             1
# 9:             7             6             5             4             3             2
# 10:             8             7             6             5             4             3
# 11:             9             8             7             6             5             4
# 12:            10             9             8             7             6             5
# V4_lag_000008 V4_lag_000009 V4_lag_000010
# 1:            NA            NA            NA
# 2:            NA            NA            NA
# 3:            NA            NA            NA
# 4:            NA            NA            NA
# 5:            NA            NA            NA
# 6:            NA            NA            NA
# 7:            NA            NA            NA
# 8:            NA            NA            NA
# 9:             1            NA            NA
# 10:             2             1            NA
# 11:             3             2             1
# 12:             4             3             2
```

Comment: Fyi, no need to wrap a function with `c(f()) := `

Comment: @Frank, I always thought I should use a `c()` when creating multiple columns. Does `data.table` will check first whether `LHS` is a function?

Comment: It is only needed in one case. `DT[, x := ]` will create a column named `x` for convenience (no need to wrap in quotes, like `"x" :=`), but this means that if you want `x` defined dynamically, it must be wrapped in parentheses, `x = "col"; DT[, (x) := ]`.

Comment: Wow!  data.table is so sexy.  I ran the dang thing all night (literally) on the data.frame and it wasn't done.  This was literally done in a few minutes.  Data.table is so very sexy.  Wow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Mike H. didn't work for me -- I think likely due to data.table updates. A modified form is:

```
lagcols <- c('test1','test2') #input column names

lagcols2<- paste0("lag",  #output column names
  rep(lag, times = length(lagcols)),'_',
  rep(lagcols, each = length(lag)))

lag <- c(1,2,10) #desired lags

dt[, (lagcols2) :=  shift(.SD, lag), by=id]
```